# to hide parent tr based on its children span value in angular ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<table class="col-md-12">
    <th>values</th>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span ng-repeat="item in items">
                <span ng-repeat="subitem in item.allowitems" ng-if "item.allowid = 1">
                    <span ng-repeat="point in subitem.points">{{point.value}}</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span ng-repeat="item in items">
                <span ng-repeat="subitem in item.allowitems" ng-if "item.allowid = 3">
                    <span ng-repeat="point in subitem.points">{{point.value}}</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span ng-repeat="item in items">
                <span ng-repeat="subitem in item.allowitems" ng-if "item.allowid = 5">
                    <span ng-repeat="point in subitem.points">{{point.value}}</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to hide the respective rows trs if the point.value is null or item.allowid is null.But how I can check with ng-if or ng-hide in the parent respective tr

Comment: Right now there are multiple items in each `<tr>`. Do you want to hide the entire row if ANY of the point.value is null or item.allowid is null?

Answer (score 0):

There may be more elegant ways to to this, but one option would be to use a directive to hide the parent `<tr>`. You'd have to include a reference to jQuery for this to work since jqLite doesn't have `.closest()` nor `.hide()`.

```
.directive('hideParent', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.closest('tr').hide();
        }
    }
})
```

Then you can use the directive when you want to hide the parent `<tr>`:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items">
    <hide-parent ng-if="item.allowid === null"></hide-parent>
    <span ng-repeat="subitem in item.allowitems" ng-if="item.allowid === 1">
        <span ng-repeat="point in subitem.points">
            {{point.value}}
            <hide-parent ng-if="point.value === null"></hide-parent>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Some people may consider this to be a hack or a dirty approach to solving the issue since you are including elements for no purpose other than to manipulate the DOM. You could always change this to an attribute on the elements containing your `ng-repeat`, but then you would have to move the logic of determining whether to hide the parent into the `hideParent` directive.